# mp4 generated with moviepy only appears as audio in vscode, and only video in finder

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a few video clips I am concatenating with moviepy. However, upon making the video file and saving it, it is not behaving expectedly.

I am using VSCode as my editor, and when I click on the generated mp4 in VSCode, I can only play the audio of the file. It is the expected audio.

On the other hand, when I navigate to the file in Finder, the mp4 only displays as a video with no audio. I am bewildered as to why this is.

When I share the video, it still is just visual with no audio.

Here is the code I am using to save:

```
titleClip = __createClip(script.titleSCFile, script.titleAudioClip, marginSize)
    print("screenshot file: ", script.titleSCFile)# screenshot file:  screenshots/<filename>.png
    print("Duration: ",script.titleAudioClip.duration) #Duration:  3.55
    titleClip.write_videofile(
        'test_combine_aud_and_vid.mp4', 
        codec = 'mpeg4',
        bitrate = config["Video"]["Bitrate"], #8000k 
        threads = config["Video"]["Threads"] #12
    )
```

The __createClip function takes in a png, an audio file, and turns it into a video clip:

```
    def __createClip(screenShotFile, audioClip, marginSize):
    imageClip = ImageClip(
        screenShotFile,
        duration=audioClip.duration
        ).set_position(("center", "center"))
    imageClip = imageClip.resize(width=(w-marginSize))
    videoClip = imageClip.set_audio(audioClip)
    videoClip.fps = 1
    return videoClip
```

I tried saving the clips before concatenating, and they have the same error. The video and audio files are of the same length too.

I expected the mp4 to be appear the same in both locations, with audio and video. This issue occurs with every image file and audio clip that I try.

EDIT: Resolved, changed the encodings. Video was fine when uploaded to something like YouTube, but the encodings I was using were not compatible.

Comment: What is `__createClip`, and can you share the original videos you're combining? Does it work with other videos?

Comment: I will add the function to the original post @Gaberocksall